# Recover deleted user profile windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, data-recovery, recovery

How can I recover a deleted user profile from windows 10 that was deleted properly?

SID not listed in:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

Is there another way to recover the profile?

Comment: Try restoring to a prior point.  Otherwise there is not any way I know to recover this kind of deletion.

Comment: Dang we cant get to a far enough restore point :(

Comment: If you have a backup of `C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM`, this registry key can be extracted from it.

Comment: I dont have a backup of that time and I am trying to get a specific browser history from back then.

Comment: You can use tools like testdisk and attempt to restore the deleted files from whatever can be scraped from the unallocated space on the drive.  You will probably not be successful.  Backup often.  Bummer.